# Direct interaction theory

Tags: waves, classical-electrodynamics, particle-physics

I got to know about a kind of theory or formulation of EM which doesn't have the idea of fields in it. In that theory I guess field isn't that which mediates the force between two charged particles. In the case of classical EM theory, we choose to say that two interacting charged particles, which are separated by certain distance, have their fields interacting or let's say that each particle is in the field of the other particle and hence experiences force.

I came across a type of theory which does not choose field as an independent degree of freedom, i.e., particles don't need an omnipresent field to exert force or transmit energy. However, intuitively I realize the necessity of something to travel from one particle to another, so as to transmit energy or let's say for the force to be exerted. So, I wanted to know what replaces fields as the link between particles .

From the comments, I got to know about an advanced version of such a theory which goes by the name of [Wheeler-Feynman absorber theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93Feynman_absorber_theory). Reading about that theory suggests involvement of waves between particles, which play the role of absorber and emitter. So are waves the agents that link up the exchange between particles? What kind of wave is being referred to in that theory?

Comment: Welcome to Physics StackExchange. I think you are asking about something like local field theories? Like, what's the difference between a photon-mediating the electron magnetic force versus the instantaneous coulomb potential description? Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: @hft : Maybe but cannot certainly say because of the jargons you have used ...Basically , I would like to know how do we view ,in direct interaction theory , the electrostatic attraction . Like when we use fields we say that the particles exert force one another by interacting with each other's fields. So , how do paricles exert force on each other according to this theory ...does something propagate or travel from one particle to another ?

Comment: Please give a reference for "direct interaction theory". I *think* you might be talking about effective field theories where the mediating field has been integrated out, but it is merely an approximation, not an equivalent theory for the physics at all scales.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : What is meant by mediating fields being integrated out ?

Comment: @SheldonKripke: It's a technical (QFT) term, see [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61197/50583).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_at_a_distance

Comment: @ACuriousMind :http://www.jameshedberg.com/docs/directactionelectrodynamics.pdf

Comment: Ah, you mean the classical version of [Wheeler-Feynman absorber theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheeler%E2%80%93Feynman_absorber_theory) formulated in terms of the Fokker action, for a somewhat rigorous treatment, see e.g. [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.1077v1). Unfortunately, your question doesn't make sense. There is no "agent" defined by the Fokker action, it's simply a non-local action functional that gives the correct physics without involving the ED fields at the level of the action.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : Would I seem to be on a vague quest if I ask that , according to these theories, which don't require the concept of field as an independent degree of freedom or a mediator between two particles , what leads to the communication between two particles ? Any kind of signal that travels from one to another ?Browsing through the web and reading few non technical articles on wheeler feynman theory , I can infer that they mentioned about the propagation of advanced and retarded waves .Is it really so ?

Comment: @ACuriousMind : Have edited my question